# Applying border-radius to bootstrap 5 table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to add a border-radius to my bootstrap 5 table.... I've done some research and many of the solutions say to wrap the table in a `div` and apply the `border-radius` to that `div`. I've attempted to do that but the border-radius has no effect on my table. I've also tried adding the border-radius class to the `table` but it still has no effect on the table.

I've applied the same css classes to the a div and the border-radius property is applied as expected.

How can I apply the border-radius to my bootstrap table?

Here is a code snippet:

```css
.tbl-container { width: 400px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;}

.bg-red {background-color:red; color:white;}

.bdr {border-radius: 6px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="tbl-container bdr">
<table class="table bdr">
  <thead class="bg-red">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>


<div class="tbl-container">
 <div class="bg-red bdr">
 TESTING BORDER
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The border radius is being applied on the parent div - it's just overflowing.

Apply `overflow:hidden` to the table parent:

```css
.tbl-container {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.bdr {
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="tbl-container bdr"> <!-- <== overflow: hidden applied to parent -->
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="bg-red">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Bootstrap has own class to use.

```html
<table class="rounded-3 overflow-hidden"></table>
```

Comment: that doesn't work well when also using table-bordered, the border is just missing in the corners. Using a wrapper card class worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667520/686654

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="table-responsive card rounded-3 p-0 m-0">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped rounded-3 border overflow-hidden p-0 m-0">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <table>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.