# How to have this HTML table with rounded corners (Boostrap 4)?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html-table

I've tried making this table's corners rounded, but none of the attempts was successful:

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/wpkog0z4/27/#&togetherjs=19BMSCeK8c)

I've tried this answer's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47094043/11832197), tried using `table-bordered`, but none worked.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to implement a table with rounded corners using Bootstrap 4 is to wrap table inside `div` with `"card"` class, like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```